# I cloned a repository and did original work to it, but the name is still in it

Tags: java, spring, file, intellij-idea, naming

I cloned an old repository to get a basic environment set up that was from my school. Now I've finished building a web application 1 month and a half later, and I just realized this shows up when you clone mine. Is there anyway to remove the brackets?

[image: How to remove the bracket?]

Answer (score 0):

Solved

It's the module name that can be configured automatically from the pom.xml  property or defined manually: